# Django Crispy Form Split Field Layouts

Tags: python, django, layout, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

We have a crispy form where we want to be able to render different fields in different parts of our forms `HTML` template, however we can't find a way of doing this in the [Crispy Documentation](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). Below is some slightly made-up code to illustrate what we are trying to do:

**forms.py**

```
helper = FormHelper()
helper.layout_1 = Layout(
    Div(
        Field('field_1a'),
        Field('field_1b')
    )
)
helper.layout_2 = Layout(
    Div(
        Field('field_2a'),
        Field('field_2b')
    )
)
```

**template.html**

```
<body>
    {% crispy form layout_1 %}
    <!-- A big bunch of other html -->
    {% crispy form layout_2 %}
</body>
```

Does anyone know a clean way of achieving this?

---

The approaches we have looked at so far and had to rule out:

- We could manually add the fields in our HTML instead of having crispy render them for us. However, this looks to be a no-go because we have a number of `choice` fields whose options are determined programmatically.
- We could write a crispy layout which uses an `crispy.forms.layout.HTML` object to include the HTML which splits up the two different parts of our layout. However, there is a lot of HTML and it would become difficult to maintain if we embedded this directly into python.
- We could write a [Custom Layout Object](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/layouts.html#creating-your-own-layout-objects) to do this for us, however we predict this would be quite involved and want to consider this a last resort.
- We could just not use crispy, and instead look for ways outside of crispy to achieve this, but then we would lose consistency with all the other forms in our application.

Comment: Is this a `ModelForm` you are working with?

Comment: Nope it's just a vanilla `django.forms.Form`

Comment: So is crispy rendering all the fields twice instead of just the ones you have specified in each layout? I didn't see a mention of what is wrong with your current solution.

Comment: We are rendering different fields in different parts of the layout. The code above doesn't actually work - this is more to illustrate what we are looking to try and do (apologies if that wasn't clear enough)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Update: This does not work for `forms.ModelForm`

Try creating two helpers instead of two layouts then explicitly calling your separate helpers. Doing it this way you will have to manually write `<form>` tags to enclose both forms in your template but hopefully provides the solution you need.

```
forms.py

class Form(forms.Form):
    field_1a = forms.CharField()
    field_1b = forms.CharField()
    field_2a = forms.CharField()
    field_2b = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper1 = FormHelper()
        self.helper1.form_tag = False
        self.helper1.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Field('field_1a'),
                Field('field_1b')
            )
        )

        self.helper2 = FormHelper()
        self.helper2.form_tag = False
        self.helper2.disable_csrf = True
        self.helper2.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Field('field_2a'),
                Field('field_2b')
            )
        )
```

Then in your template:

```
<body>
<form>
{% crispy form form.helper1 %}
<!-- A big bunch of other html -->
{% crispy form form.helper2 %}
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: @scott I am trying this out, but the problem is the second helper renders (again) fields which were in the first helper too. Any clues?

Comment: This doesn't work when using a ModelForm. Every form field is being output by each helper, despite what fields are in the layout.

Comment: @EronVillarreal for ModelForms you can do a `if hasattr(self.Meta, 'fields'): delattr(self.Meta, 'fields')` at the end of the `__init__` block to hack your way around that

Answer (score 1):

create a form.py

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Field,Layout, ButtonHolder, Submit
class layout1Form(forms.Form):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(layout1Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
           Field('answer',css_class="field span8"),
           ButtonHolder(
              Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-primary pull-right')
            )
          )
        self.helper.form_tag = False

class layout2Form(forms.Form):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(layout1Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
           Field('answer',css_class="field span8"),
           ButtonHolder(
              Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-primary pull-right')
            )
          )
        self.helper.form_tag = False
```

then in views.py

#### views.py

```
from ...forms import layout1Form,layout2Form
def layouttest(request):
    form = layout1Form(request.POST)
    form1=layout2Form(request.POST)
    return render(request,'test.html',{'frm1':form,'frm2':form1})
```

then in templates you can use in

#### test.html

```
<form id="signup" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
{% crispy frm1 %}
   ""the big html""
{% crispy frm2 %}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>   
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @suhail, we had considered using HTML elements however we have a lot of HTML between different parts of the layout, and want to avoid having to embed so much HTML into the python code (as it will be more difficult to maintain the HTML).

Comment: @robjohncox may be you can use a template like `self.helper['<fieldname>'].wrap(Field, template="<template path>")`

Comment: Interesting, that looks like it could work. We may just go this way - going to wait to see what other suggestions people may have.

Comment: @robjohncox i have updated my answer in some other ways to . actually i am using crispyforms. and these are taken from my working project

Comment: Ah so it could be split into two forms, that makes sense. For our use-case another approach (from @scottwoodall) fits a bit better, but still a neat solution so +1 for you.